# Add a fix value to a dataframe (accumulating to future ones)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to simulate inventory level during the next 6 months:

1- I have the expected accumulated demand for each day of next 6 months.
[image]
 So, with no reorder, my balance would be more negative everyday.

2- My idea is:
 Everytime the inventory level is lower than 3000, I would send an order to buy 10000, and after 3 days, my level would increase again:
[image]

How is the best way to add this value into all the future values ?

```
       ds         saldo
0 2019-01-01  10200.839819
1 2019-01-02   5219.412952
2 2019-01-03      3.161876
3 2019-01-04  -5507.506201
4 2019-01-05 -10730.291221
5 2019-01-06 -14406.833593
6 2019-01-07 -17781.500396
7 2019-01-08 -21545.503098
8 2019-01-09 -25394.427708
```

I started doing like this :

```
c = 0
for index, row in forecast_data.iterrows():
  if row['saldo'] < 3000:
    c += 1
    if c == 3:
      row['saldo'] + 10000
      c = 0
```

But it just adds to the actual row, not for the accumulated future ones.

```
print(row['ds'], row['saldo'])
9 2019-01-10 -29277.647817
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only adding 1000 to the `row`, not to every entry that follows. Try replacing

```
row['saldo'] + 10000
```

with

```
forecast_data['saldo'][index:] += forecast_data['saldo'][index:] + 1000
```

This will add 1000 to every following entry.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign the value i think. use `row['saldo'] += 10000` instead of `row['saldo'] + 10000`